# Virtual electron charge

Tags: charge, quantum-electrodynamics, virtual-particles

Since the total charge of an actual electron has been shown to have a contribution from virtual electrons, what is the value of the virtual electron charge contribution?

Answer (score 2):

In standard QED, the “bare” charge is infinite and the quantum correction to it from virtual particles is infinite, producing the finite charge that we measure. The same thing happens with the mass. This infinite “renormalization” of the charge and the mass, arising from the assumption that the electron is a *point* particle, doesn’t seem particularly satisfying to many physicists, but for now it is standard physics and, more importantly, *it works*, allowing QED to correctly predict some quantities to one part in a trillion!